# How to clear cache for a subject in Shiro

Tags: permissions, shiro, cache-invalidation

Shiro provides cache feature but in my case, I'm using dynamic roles and permissions for the users. I need to expire the cache for a particular user if any so that changes in permissions immediately affect to user.

There is a method in Realm, but how I get an instance of associated realm to invoke method to clear cache.

Answer (score 6):

I ended up exposing the private method "clearCachedAuthorizationInfo" in the extended Realm of AuthorizingRealm.  Then just pass in the principals.

```java
public class MyRealm extends AuthorizingRealm {
    //...
    @Override
    public void clearCachedAuthorizationInfo(PrincipalCollection principals)
    {
        super.clearCachedAuthorizationInfo(principals);
    }
    //...
}
```

to clear the authorization cache:

```java
realm.clearCachedAuthorizationInfo( SecurityUtils.getSubject().getPrincipals() );
```

I think this is a bit cleaner/safer because this method has additional checks against `null` on the cache and will ensure you get a reference to the cache if one exists.  Simply calling `getAuthorizationCache()` doesn't do this and may or may not work all the time.

You do need to maintain a reference to the realm.  I did this by initializing Shiro via Spring and then injecting it as a Singleton bean wherever I needed it.

Comment: Hey Thanks for response. But I am not using spring so i have to configure shiro using INI they how I will get the realm instance used by shiro. I tried to configure shiro through java code, but java-code configuration doesn't work it says no realm configured.

Comment: To fetch all the realms available you can use:


Collection<Realm> realms = ((RealmSecurityManager)SecurityUtils.getSecurityManager()).getRealms();


You can then see which realms have the method that exposed clearing the Authorization Info and call it on those realms.

Answer (score 1):

If you check out the source of the method getAuthorizationInfo in AuthorizingRealm, you see it is simply using a key/value store to cache the authorization info.

It uses the PrincipalCollection object as a key.

So if you call something like:

```
realm.getAuthorizationCache().remove(SecurityUtils.getSubject().getPrincipals())
```

the cache should normally be cleared.